# Saving a root object in Entity Framework 6 (but not the entire context)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, save, dbcontext, persistent

I try to save a root object in entity framework, but not all objects of a context. It seems to be a basic feature of entity framework and I really do not see how to do it.

I do use a the following generic DbContext

```
class GenericContext<T> : DbContext
{
  DbSet<T> Objs;

  SaveChanges( ICollection<T> validatedObjs )
  {
...
  }
}
```

My question :
**How can I implement the SaveChanges method in order to save all validatedObjs even thoses related to T ?**

T is a root object of a data grape.

All objects of the context not related to validatedObjs must not be saved, even if they are in modified state.

If T has not been modified but an object related to T has been modified, I need the saving to be made.

For example if T = Car

```
class Car
{
   IList<Wheel> wheels;
}

// changing the color of one wheel:
Car car1 = new Car();
Car car2 = new Car();
car1.wheels[0].color = Color.red;
car2.wheels[0].color = Color.Blue;
```

We have:

```
Entry( car1 ).EntityState = Unchanged
Entry( car2 ).EntityState = Unchanged
Entry( car1.wheels[0] ).EntityState = Modified
Entry( car2.wheels[0] ).EntityState = Modified
```

if userValidated contains car1 but not car2, only the wheels of the car1 must be saved in database.

Comment: what's a data grape? ^^ I was assuming it was a typo of group, but it's done twice :O

Comment: Perhaps just use a separate Context instance for your grape updates.

Comment: "data grape" I mean a tree, with a root object. In french we use the grape for analogy.

Comment: I'm trying to use another dedicated context the saving works that context but the original context that references the same Car is in a bad state makes the saving crashes.